# passing props in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, prop

I am new to vue and I am having problems passing props from one component to another and I need help

events.js

```
              <div class="location__time-details">
  <h3 class="location__subheader">{{ event.venue }}</h3>
 <CartManagement :event="event"/>
</div>
</div>
```

I am trying to get the properties from **event**

Cart.js

```
 props: ["id", "event"],
```

defined the props

```
data: function() {
    return {
      regular: null,
      event:"",
     
    };
    
  },
```

Passed it

```
 <h1 class="modal__text">{{ event.name}}</h1>
```

But the error shows Duplicate key, what am I doing wrong and what is the solution?

Comment: Remove `event: "",` from your `data`. You can't have it both in props and in data

Comment: It reads cannot read property of name undefined.

Comment: That message means that the `event` you are passing to `<CartManagement :event="event"/>` is `undefined`. Hard to tell just by looking at the snippets you posted, though

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have both data and props with the same name. Remove `event` from your data. And you can give a default value of your props as follow.

```
props : {
   ...
   event : {
       type : 'Object',
       default : function(){
           return {
               name : ''
               // and other fields
           };
       }
   }
}
```